# NodeJS v4 or io.js on Cloudbees

Tags: node.js, cloudbees

I would like to test and build my node server on Cloudbees using io.js, preferably keeping up with the newer versions (3.2.0 as of today).

Currently, I am using NodeJS 0.10.x on Cloudbees based on the following tutorial. However, I have been unable to find anything about io.js.
https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Node+Builds

Has anyone tried this? Do I need to install io.js manually?

***Update:***

NodeJS has now released v4.0.0. This is also not supported on Cloudbees, but I am highly interested. Same problem still applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW, I ended up solving this with NVM.

In the Jenkins free style job, open an "Execute shell" build action.

```sh
 #!/bin/sh

 {
   # try
   nvm which
 } || {
   # catch
   curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.30.1/install.sh | bash
   source ~/.bash_profile > /dev/null
 }

 nvm install stable > /dev/null

 node -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins doesn't provide an auto-installer for it (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29697) but you can use Custom Tools installer to install it manually by using something similar to: https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205299940-Install-a-new-NodeJS-version

Best regards

Comment: Thanks for the input. The "custom tools" plugin is a nice, but the specific example shown is the same as from my original link. It pulls down cached versions of NodeJS from Cloudbees' internal storage. It works great if the version you want is supported. Unfortunately, the latest available version of NodeJS is 0.12.7 (from the fc17 directory), and there is nothing for io.js or NodeJS 4.0.0.